# How to solve the lambda / SAM problem in Kotlin multiplatform library projects?

Tags: java, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

I have a problem with SAMs in Kotlin. I'm working on a library which has functions which accept a lambda. My problem is that I can't simply write this:

```
fun myFun(someLambda: (A) -> B) {
    // ...
}
```

because if a Java user would like to call it they would need to pass a `Function1` to it which is not very good UX. If I create a SAM instead:

```
fun myFun(someSam: Function<A, B>) {
    // ...
}
```

then it is cumbersome for Kotlin users. What I've been doing so far is that I went the SAM way and added an extension function for all of these functions for Kotlin users which just translates to the SAM function:

```
inline fun <A, B> MyClass.someFun(crossinline fn: (A) -> B) {
    return someFun(object : Function<A, B> {
        override fun accept(value: A): B {
            return fn.invoke(value)
        }
    })
}
```

This method comes with a lot of boilerplate and it is also hard to maintain. Is there a better alternative to solve this problem?

Comment: Why not both? Just let it overload.

Comment: I'm using both, but it comes with **a lot** of boilerplate. I'm looking for a solution which lets me write less and maintainable code.

Comment: So the problem is SAM conversion on function calls only happens when calling java from kotlin but not calling kotlin from kotlin... why so dumb. Is it possible to request this feature from the kotlin team?

Comment: The answers are fine for Java, but not for *multiplatform*.
A "fun" interface doesn't get correctly translated into a lambda targeting JS/TS.

Comment: @LppEdd do you plan on adding an answer that solves this problem?

Comment: @AdamArold Unfortunately, not at the moment. But I have this question bookmarked.

Answer (score 2):

In kotlin 1.4 you can now declare functional (SAM) interfaces like this:

```
fun interface MyFunction {
    fun doSomething(input: Int): Boolean
}
```

Note the "fun" keyword in front of the interface declaration. This will allow using a lambda from both kotlin and java.

See also https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/fun-interfaces.html

Answer (score 0):

I just added convenience functions that allowed me to easily convert the Java functional interfaces to their Kotlin counterpart, but put them in back-ticks (which I don't like to see in regular Kotlin code (in contrast to tests) ;-)), e.g.:

```
fun <T> `$consume`(consumer: Consumer<T>): (T) -> Unit = consumer::accept
fun <T, R> `$`(func: java.util.function.Function<T, R>): (T) -> R = func::apply
fun <T, U, R> `$`(func: java.util.function.BiFunction<T, U, R>): (T, U) -> R = func::apply
// etc.
```

Assuming you have the following functions in Kotlin:

```
fun doSomething1(c : (String) -> Unit) : String = TODO()
fun doSomething2(f : (String) -> String) : String = TODO()
fun doSomething3(f : (String, String) -> String) : String = TODO()
```

Usage from Java could then look like:

```
doSomething1($consume((e) -> System.out.println(e)));
doSomething2($((e) -> e + "ok"));
doSomething3($((e1, e2) -> String.join(", ", e1, e2)));
```

Note that I used `$consume` to overcome the ambiguity regarding `Function<T, R>`. You could also use `$` for the consumer, but then you would need either curly brackets or would have to cast it to the `Consumer<T>`-interace in order to take advantage of method references, e.g.:

```
doSomething1($((e) -> { System.out.println(e); }));
doSomething1($((Consumer<String>) System.out::println));
```

The main benefit of using `$` with the back-ticks is, that in Kotlin you will probably not use it, as it isn't so easily writable (who starts with back-ticks when calling functions?) and code completion doesn't suggest it that easily.

Furthermore the `$`-sign is directly callable on the Java side without problem.

Maybe you want to mix your overloading functions with this so you do not need to implement all the overloading code itself and put those functions in its own library available for Java developers?

Comment: I would really not like something like that if I was a user. The point is to have *idiomatic* interface for both Java and Kotlin users.

Comment: Well... I also wanted to advertise the usage of Kotlin a bit ;-) for that it is good.. maybe you want to generate these overloads then?

Comment: hmmm... if the new type inference is the default, than your code using the Java functional types would be as usable as if you would have the Kotlin functional types in place, right? Did you already experiment with the new type inference?

Comment: Note that my problem is only in a multiplatform environment. I don't have access to any Java code.

Comment: Well.. in your question you narrow it down to Java/Kotlin interop... AFAIK, the new type inference could help you out here... wanted to play with own functional types and also with `actual`/`expect` so that, maybe each platform sees its possible variants only... However didn't have time yet and will probably not have for more than 3 weeks...

Comment: And yes.. for multiplatform it could be that the new type inference alone doesn't help you out here... I set my hope on platform specific implementations ;-)